# How can i decode an image and save it into database in pl sql?

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql

problem sqldeveloper: Image could not be decoded from the binary stream.

I'm sending this information that is coming from an uploaded image and it's src attribute is encoding in this way: blob:https://**domain**/e0bac53c-1151-4142-a258-84deb37b2a42 with ajax call with javascript and in pl sql I'm trying to save the image into oracle database but is not decoded right:

I'm sending the pl sql code to show you how to insert the image in oracle database:

```
DECLARE
l_base64_str CLOB;
l_base64_str_before_resize CLOB;
l_blob BLOB;
l_blob_before_resize BLOB;

v_blob_url CLOB := :P8_IMAGE_BEFORE_RESIZING;
v_raw RAW (32767);
v_binary BLOB;
v_image_before BLOB;

l_http_request   UTL_HTTP.req;
l_http_response  UTL_HTTP.resp;
l_raw            RAW(32767);

l_blob_before    BLOB;
l_blob_length number;
l_file utl_file.file_type;


BEGIN
    l_base64_str := SUBSTR(:P8_RESIZED_IMAGE, INSTR(:P8_RESIZED_IMAGE, ',') + 1);
    l_base64_str_before_resize := SUBSTR(:P8_IMAGE_BEFORE_RESIZING, INSTR(:P8_IMAGE_BEFORE_RESIZING, ',') + 1);

    
    l_blob := Utl_Encode.Base64_Decode(UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(l_base64_str));

    v_blob_url := SUBSTR (v_blob_url, INSTR (v_blob_url, ':') + 1);
    v_raw := UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE (UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (v_blob_url));

    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY (v_binary, TRUE);
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND (v_binary, SYS.DBMS_lob.getlength (v_raw), v_raw);

    INSERT INTO UPLOAD_IMAGES (ID, IMAGE_BEFORE, IMAGE_AFTER, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, ALTITUDE, FILENAME, MIMETYPE, DATETIME, RESIZED_IMAGE, EXIF, GEOMETRY) VALUES (UPLOAD_IMAGES_SEQ.nextval, EMPTY_BLOB(), l_blob, :P8_LATITUDE, :P8_LONGITUDE, :P8_ALTITUDE, :P8_FILENAME, :P8_MIMETYPE, sysdate, l_base64_str, :P8_EXIF, SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 4326, SDO_POINT_TYPE(:P8_LONGITUDE, :P8_LATITUDE, :P8_ALTITUDE), NULL, NULL))
    RETURNING IMAGE_BEFORE INTO v_image_before;
    DBMS_LOB.WRITE (v_image_before, LENGTH(v_binary), 1, v_binary);

    COMMIT;

    
    apex_json.open_object;  
    apex_json.write('success', true);  
    apex_json.close_object; 
END;
```

I'm also adding the JavaScript code. The below code it uploads one or more images resize them and read them metadata.

```
    jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
$(function () {
    let dropTimer;
    let dropTarget = $('.dragArea');
    let fileInput = $('#imageFile');
    dropTarget.on("dragover", function (event) {
        dropTarget.addClass('over');
        return false; // Required for drop to work
    });
    dropTarget.on('dragleave', function (event) {
        dropTarget.removeClass('over');
    });
    handleDrop = function (files) {
        console.log('files', files);
        dropTarget.removeClass('over');
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            let file = files[i];
            console.log(file);

            if (files.length > apex.item("P8_NUMBER_OF_IMAGES").getValue()) {
                alert(`You cannot select more than ${apex.item("P8_NUMBER_OF_IMAGES").getValue()} files`);
                return;
            } else {
                const fileSize = files[i].size / 1024 / 1024; // in MiB
                if (fileSize > apex.item("P8_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE").getValue()) {
                    alert(`File size exceeds ${apex.item("P8_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE").getValue()} MB`);
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (file.type.match('image.*')) {
                let notResizeImage = document.createElement("img");

                let reader = new FileReader();

                let BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
                function convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI) {
                    let base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
                    let base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index);
                    let raw = window.atob(base64);
                    let rawLength = raw.length;
                    let array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

                    for (i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
                        array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
                    }
                    return array;
                }
                reader.onload = function (e) {

                    let base64data = e.target.result;
                    console.log('base64data', base64data);
                    let binaryString = convertDataURIToBinary(base64data);
                    let blob = new Blob([binaryString], { type: file.type });
                    let urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                    let imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);

                    // set the src attribute of the new image element to the image URL
                    $(notResizeImage).attr('src', imageUrl);

                    // append the new image element to the imageBeforeResizing element
                    $('.imageBeforeResizing').append(notResizeImage);

                    apex.item("P8_IMAGE_BEFORE_RESIZING").setValue(imageUrl);
                    console.log("P8_IMAGE_BEFORE_RESIZING", apex.item("P8_IMAGE_BEFORE_RESIZING").getValue())
                    $('.imageBeforeResizing').hide();
                    console.log("byteArray", imageUrl);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);

                resizeImage(file, 100, function (result) {
                    console.log('file', file);
                    console.log('result', result);
                    $('.resultImageWrapper').append(
                        $('<img>', { src: result }).attr('id', 'resized-image')
                    )
                    $('.resultImageWrapper').show();

                    fileReader = new FileReader();
                    let array;
                    fileReader.onload = function (e) {
                        apex.item("P8_RESIZED_IMAGE").setValue(result)
                        console.log("P8_RESIZED_IMAGE", apex.item("P8_RESIZED_IMAGE").getValue())
                        apex.item("P8_FILENAME").setValue(file.name);
                        console.log('filename', apex.item("P8_FILENAME").getValue());
                        apex.item("P8_MIMETYPE").setValue(file.type)

                        let myData = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(e.target.result);
                        console.log('exif', myData);
                        apex.item("P8_EXIF").setValue(JSON.stringify(myData));
                        console.log("P8_EXIF", apex.item("P8_EXIF").getValue());


                        function ConvertDMSToDD(degrees, minutes, seconds, direction) {

                            let dd = degrees + (minutes / 60) + (seconds / 3600);

                            if (direction == "S" || direction == "W") {
                                dd = dd * -1;
                            }

                            return dd;
                        }

                        // Calculate latitude decimal
                        if (myData.GPSLatitude) {
                            let latDegree = myData.GPSLatitude[0].numerator / myData.GPSLatitude[0].denominator;
                            let latMinute = myData.GPSLatitude[1].numerator / myData.GPSLatitude[1].denominator;
                            let latSecond = myData.GPSLatitude[2].numerator / myData.GPSLatitude[2].denominator;
                            if (myData.GPSLatitudeRef) {
                                let latDirection = myData.GPSLatitudeRef;

                                let latFinal = ConvertDMSToDD(latDegree, latMinute, latSecond, latDirection);
                                if (latFinal) {
                                    apex.item("P8_LATITUDE").setValue(latFinal)
                                    console.log('latFinal', $v("P8_LATITUDE"));
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // Calculate longitude decimal
                        if (myData.GPSLongitude) {
                            let lonDegree = myData.GPSLongitude[0].numerator / myData.GPSLongitude[0].denominator;
                            let lonMinute = myData.GPSLongitude[1].numerator / myData.GPSLongitude[1].denominator;
                            let lonSecond = myData.GPSLongitude[2].numerator / myData.GPSLongitude[2].denominator;
                            if (myData.GPSLongitudeRef) {
                                let lonDirection = myData.GPSLongitudeRef;

                                let lonFinal = ConvertDMSToDD(lonDegree, lonMinute, lonSecond, lonDirection);
                                if (lonFinal) {
                                    apex.item("P8_LONGITUDE").setValue(lonFinal)
                                    console.log('lonFinal', $v("P8_LONGITUDE"));
                                }
                            }
                        }



                        // Altitude
                        if (myData.GPSAltitude) {
                            let altitude = myData.GPSAltitude.numerator / myData.GPSAltitude.denominator;
                            apex.item("P8_ALTITUDE").setValue(altitude)
                            console.log('altitude', $v("P8_ALTITUDE"));
                        }

                        apex.server.process("ajax_save", {
                            pageItems: "#P8_IMAGE_BEFORE,#P8_IMAGE_AFTER,#P8_LATITUDE,#P8_LONGITUDE,#P8_ALTITUDE,#P8_MIMETYPE,#P8_FILENAME,#P8_DATETIME,#P8_RESIZED_IMAGE,#P8_IMAGE_BEFORE_RESIZING,#P8_EXIF"
                        }, {
                            // dataType: 'text',
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert("Image Uploaded", data)
                            },
                            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            }
                        });

                    };
                    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            } else {
                alert("That file wasn't an image.");
            }
        }
    };
    dropTarget.on('drop', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Or else the browser will open the file
        handleDrop(event.dataTransfer.files);
    });
    fileInput.on('change', function (event) {
        handleDrop(event.target.files);
    });
    resizeImage = function (file, size, callback) {
        let image = new Image();
        image.onload = function () {
            let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            if (image.width > size) {
                image.height *= size / image.width;
                image.width = size;
            }
            let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.width = image.width;
            canvas.height = image.height;
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
            const newBase64 = canvas.toDataURL(file.type, file);
            callback(newBase64);
        };

        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            let base64data = reader.result;
            image.src = base64data;
            console.log('image.src', image.src);
        }

    };
    console.log('blob before2', $v("P8_IMAGE_BEFORE"));
});


const fileInput = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");

const validateSize = ((input) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < input.files[i].length; i++) {
        file = files[i];
        console.log(file);
        const fileSize = input.files[i].size / 1024 / 1024; // in MiB
        if (fileSize > apex.item("P8_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE").getValue()) {
            alert(`File size exceeds ${apex.item("P8_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE").getValue()} MB`);
            return;
        }

    }
});

fileInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
    const fileList = fileInput.files;
    if (fileList.length > apex.item("P8_NUMBER_OF_IMAGES").getValue()) {
        alert(`You cannot select more than ${apex.item("P8_NUMBER_OF_IMAGES").getValue()} files`);
        return;
    } else {
        validateSize(fileInput);
    }
});
```

The response is returnig 200 but the image is not showing.

Comment: what is the value of P8_IMAGE_BEFORE_RESIZING?  Is that an URL or a BLOB?

Comment: it's in this format: `blob:https://domain/e0bac53c-1151-4142-a258-84deb37b2a42`

Comment: you are persisting the url, not the thing that the url points to.  If you have an URL to an image, don't you need to download the image?   This is not clear from your code.

Comment: You might want to edit your question and add your Javascript code as well. Normally once you've uploaded a file in Apex, you can simply copy the BLOB record from the temporary table WWV_FLOW_FILES to your permanent table.

Comment: I have edited my question and I posted the full PL/SQL code with my JavaScript code

Comment: @kfinity thank you for the response. I used WWV_FLOW_FILES but it didn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I'll try to download the image with PL/SQL. Any addintional code will be helipful.

Comment: @OldProgrammer when i try some code for download the image I'm getting an error like this: ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-29264: unknown or unsupported URL scheme

But the image src is of this type: `blob:https://domain/e0bac53c-1151-4142-a258-84deb37b2a42`. If i remove blob it will be not be correct